# when I use thisworkbook inside a function in excel vba code it doesnt work

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know where is the error in this code:

```
Function QUOTES() As String
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Range("D4").Value
End Function

Sub test()
MsgBox QUOTES 'THIS SHOWS AN ERROR!!!!
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Range("D4").Value 'THIS WORKS FINE
End Sub
```

I expect that If I call the function "QUOTES" it would work , but it does not!

Comment: `QUOTES = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Range("D4").Value`